# How to pass the parameter from controller to FormDialog state model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, botframework

**Requirement**
FormStateModel already contains FIRST input that users types.

**Code**
Simply I want to put the string that is in **activity.Text** inside FormStateModel:

```
private IDialog<FormStateModel> MakeRootDialog(string input)
    {
        return Chain.From(() => new FormDialog<FormStateModel>(
            new FormStateModel() { Question = input },
            ContactDetailsForm.BuildForm,
            FormOptions.None));
    }
```

=

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(
                    toBot: activity,
                    MakeRoot: () => this.MakeRootDialog(activity.Text));
    }
    else
    {
        await HandleSystemMessageAsync(activity);
    }

    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

On ConversationUpdate I start conversation simply by asking "Please type your Question:"

```
private static async Task<Activity> HandleSystemMessageAsync(Activity message)
        {
            switch (message.Type)
            {
                case ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData:
                    break;

                case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
                    await Welcome(message);
                    break;
(...)
```

In that way:

```
    private static async Task Welcome(Activity activity)
    {
        (...)
        reply.Text = string.Format("Hello, how can we help you today? Please type your Question:");

        await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        (...)
    }
```

But I can not find a way how to pass it. In this case this exception occurs:

```
anonymous method closures that capture the environment are not serializable, consider removing environment capture or using a reflection serialization surrogate:
```

Is there any way around that to populate state model at this step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by calling RootDialog inside MessagesController, then Calling new FormDialog by context.Call(form, (...));

```
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
        {
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new LayerDialog());
        }
```

LayerDialog:

```
   [Serializable]
    public class LayerDialog: IDialog<IMessageActivity>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(this.OnMessageReceivedAsync);
        }

    private async Task OnMessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var awaited = await result;

        FormStateModel model = new FormStateModel();
        model.Value = awaited.Text;

        var form = new FormDialog<FormStateModel >(model ,
            BuildForm , FormOptions.PromptInStart);

        context.Call(form , this.AfterResume);
    }
```